# Property of function with given negative variation

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow R$, where $-\infty<a<b<+\infty$.  Suppose also that $f(x)+x$ is non-decreasing, with $f(b)-f(a)>b-a$.  Show that there necessarily exist values $x^*\in [a,b]$ and $f^*\in (f(a),f(b))$ such that, for all $x<x^*$ we have $f(x)\leq f^*$, while for all $x>x^*$ we have $f(x)\geq f^*$.

Comments:  If the function $f$ were strictly increasing, it is easy to find $x^*$ and $f^*$ with the desired property (we could take any $f^* \in (f(a),f(b))$ together with an appropriate value for $x^*$).  Therefore I am expecting that for a function whose negative variation is sufficiently small, we must be able to find SOME $x^*$ and $f^*$ with the desired property.  Intuitively, we can draw some horizontal line $y=c$ for $c\in(f(a),f(b))$ such that the function lies above $c$ to the right and below $c$ to the left.